# Facebook grabs wrong pictures and description from playstore

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, sharing

I have a game developed using unity3D for android published on PlayStore.
Previously name of my game was ABC, but now I have changed the name to XYZ. what happening is basically when I share the link of play store on Facebook. It shows preview with the name ABC and old pictures. On clicking it routes to same correct link with fine data on it.
What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your google play link into this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/